# What is difference between git commit -am and git -m

Tags: git

Can someone state the difference between `git commit -am` and some use `git commit -m`, both works but I don't know what is the difference.

Comment: Can't you read the [funny manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) ?

Comment: `-a`: "*Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have to use "git commit -a" rather than just "git commit"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459927/why-do-i-have-to-use-git-commit-a-rather-than-just-git-commit)

Comment: @RC. might want to find a better one probably. The linked thread doesn't talk of `-am` anywhere.

Comment: @nullpointer see accepted answer, I don't think the OP is asking about the meaning of  `-m`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding when to use git commit -m and git commit -am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864175/understanding-when-to-use-git-commit-m-and-git-commit-am)

Answer (score 3):

```
git commit -am
```

is a combination of

```
// add all files staged for the commit
git commit -a   

// commit with the message
git commit -m ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Git commit -am adds stages all your files before commiting.